# django mongo db not in query error while check if name exist in a list

Tags: django, mongodb

```
from django.db import models

class SeekerRegister(models.Model):
    seeker_name               = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True,blank=True)
    seeker_email              = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True,blank=True)
    seeker_contact_no         = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True,blank=True)
    seeker_password           = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True,blank=True)
    seeker_ssp                = models.CharField(max_length=32,null=True,blank=True)
    verified                  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    type                      = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    is_seeker_profile_updated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.seeker_name



class KeySkills(models.Model):
    skills            = models.TextField()
    versions          = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,default=None)
    experience        = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,default=None)
    user              = models.ForeignKey(access_models.SeekerRegister,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='key_skills',null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "KeySkills"
```

Query i am using:

```
    SeekerRegister.objects.exclude(key_skills__skills__in=['python']).all()
```

errors:

```
        SQLDecodeError at /api/seeker/advance/search/
        FAILED SQL: SELECT "access_seekerregister"."id", "access_seekerregister"."seeker_name", "access_seekerregister"."seeker_email", "access_seekerregister"."seeker_contact_no", "access_seekerregister"."seeker_password", "access_seekerregister"."seeker_ssp", "access_seekerregister"."verified", "access_seekerregister"."type", "access_seekerregister"."is_seeker_profile_updated" FROM "access_seekerregister" INNER JOIN "seeker_keyskills" ON ("access_seekerregister"."id" = "seeker_keyskills"."user_id") INNER JOIN "seeker_candidatecompanydetails" ON ("access_seekerregister"."id" = "seeker_candidatecompanydetails"."user_id") INNER JOIN "seeker_contactinfo" ON ("access_seekerregister"."id" = "seeker_contactinfo"."user_id") INNER JOIN "seeker_candidatedetails" ON ("access_seekerregister"."id" = "seeker_candidatedetails"."user_id") INNER JOIN "seeker_candidateeducationdetails" ON ("access_seekerregister"."id" = "seeker_candidateeducationdetails"."user_id") WHERE (NOT ("access_seekerregister"."id" IN (SELECT U1."user_id" FROM "seeker_keyskills" U1 WHERE (U1."skills" IN (%(0)s) AND U1."user_id" IS NOT NULL))) AND "seeker_keyskills"."skills" IN (%(1)s, %(2)s) AND "seeker_keyskills"."skills" IN (%(3)s) AND "seeker_candidatecompanydetails"."designation" iLIKE %(4)s AND "seeker_contactinfo"."current_location" iLIKE %(5)s AND "seeker_contactinfo"."job_type" = %(6)s AND "seeker_candidatedetails"."notice_period" <= %(7)s AND "seeker_contactinfo"."gender" = %(8)s AND "seeker_contactinfo"."diferently_abled" = %(9)s AND "seeker_candidateeducationdetails"."degree" iLIKE %(10)s)
        Pymongo error: OrderedDict([('ok', 0.0), ('errmsg', "Unrecognized expression '$nin'"), ('code', 168), ('codeName', 'InvalidPipelineOperator')])
        Version: 1.2.30

        Request Method: GET
        Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/seeker/advance/search/?skills_any=python,react&notice_period=30&gender=1&job_type=1&position=ceo&degree=bachelor%20degree&current_location=bengaluru&disables=true&skills_must=react
        Django Version: 2.1.3
        Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/python
        Python Version: 3.6.7
        Python Path: ['/usr/src/jobster_api/src', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
        Server time: Mon, 14 Jan 2019 21:55:07 +0530
        Installed Applications:
        ['django.contrib.admin',
         'django.contrib.auth',
         'django.contrib.contenttypes',
         'django.contrib.sessions',
         'django.contrib.messages',
         'django.contrib.staticfiles',
         'corsheaders',
         'rest_framework',
         'django_elasticsearch_dsl',
         'seeker',
```

Here i am trying to filter with related fields using above query and getting above errors.

I want to check if name is not exist in list.
and trying with exclude

PLease have a look into it

Answer (score 1):

You make typo
Change this

```
SeekerRegister.objects.filter(seeker_name__nin=['soubhagya']).values()
```

to

```
SeekerRegister.objects.exclude(id__in=[1,2,3]).values('key_skills__experience')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186684/discussion-on-answer-by-shafikur-rahman-django-mongo-db-not-in-query-error-while).